# How to handle auto suggestion in Selenium with java?

Tags: selenium

I want to select one option from City field & that field has auto suggestion. How can we handle this? THanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Actions class to send keys.ARROW_DOWN -> then use getText -> and then verify if expected city is listed or not.

Comment: I tried that but still not working. It says, element not interactable.
This is inspected CIty field
<input name="ctl00$MainRegion$UserRegistration$AddressCtrl$PostcodeText" type="text" id="PostcodeText" class="width55per" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();" data-hj-suppress="" autocomplete="off">

Comment: Try using explicit wait with ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable.